# Flutter How to disable firebase app network read/write for a week?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to disable firebase app read/write for a week and user firebase cache, then enable it for updating user info and then disable it until next week, is it possible?

Comment: Sure, but you're going to have to write a lot of code for that.  There isn't a simple setting you use to implement this.

Comment: Can't we disable network or specify the source of  to get data from server or cache.

Comment: Which database are you referring to?  You tagged two different databases here.

Comment: Also you might want to say more about *why* you want to do this.  What's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: I want to make minimum read and writes, like if user change there setting, i only update it once in a day

Comment: That's not really a supported use case for the Firestore SDK.  It would be better to write to a local database, and synchronize that with Firestore as needed.  The SDK generally assumes that you mostly want to use the cloud services over an active connection, and the cache is there for the moments when you don't, so the app can keep working.

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the source of getting data from server or cache or server first:

`Source.cache`            : get data from the cache
`Source.server`           : get data from the server
`Source.serverAndCache`   : (Default) get data from the server first

```
 Firestore.instance
        .collection("user")
        .getDocuments(source: Source.cache)
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        print("get document from cache: " + doc.toString());
      });
    });
```

You can even check if your data is from cache or server:

```
   querySnapshot.metadata.isFromCache;
```

Comment: That doesn't disable the database though.  That just tells the client where to go. The database can still service requests.